# Tracking file downloads in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, download

I'd like to know if anyone knows of a way I could track whether a user has downloaded a file in WordPress. I would need to track the same file for multiple users but have no idea of the best way to go about doing it.

Is there a plugin that does this?

We're also using WooCommerce if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion with a code that I'm using to serve images

code:

```
// neads parameter $filePath
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filePath));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

When user clicks to a file link you can redirect them to page containing similar code. There you can easily implement som kinde of counter (using SQL)